# Swift coordinates of a pressed button

Tags: swift, button

I'm working on a tic tac toe game (3x3), so I have 9 buttons and what I want to do is to get coordinates of a button which user had pressed and insert an image on the place of the button.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1Outlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        let imageName = "IMG.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
        view.addSubview(imageView)


}
```

I know I can get coordinates of the button using `button1Outlet.center` , but I need something like `this.center` to avoid hardcoding it for every button.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the sender to a `UIButton` which you then can access any frame related methods on.

```
(sender as UIButton).center
```

Answer (score 1):

When a button is clicked it is passed as a parameter to the function. Just use the `sender`.

```
// Change sender to a UIButton type
@IBAction func button1Action(sender: UIButton) {
    // ... Setup your views

    // Set same frames
    imageView.frame = sender.frame
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    // If you want to remove the button
    sender.removeFromSuperview()
}
```